# imports while starting an interactive shell

Tags: python, django, shell, import

When I start the interactive django shell through manage.py, by executing

```
python -v manage.py shell
```

from the project directory, I see a lot of modules of format django.package.module getting imported in the verbose output but still I have to import them to use it in the shell.

The same happens when I just run the Python shell (with the -v argument). For example I see this in the verbose output,

```
import os # precompiled from /usr/local/gdp/lib/python2.4/os.pyc
```

but still i have to do import os to import and use the os module. What is being imported that am seeing in the verbose output and why I have to import them explicitly again to use them in the shell? Does Python load some essential modules while starting the shell or is it some kind of behind-the-scene magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-v` traces the **first** import of a module -- the one that actually **loads** the module (executes its code, and so may take a bit of time) and sticks it into `sys.modules`.

That has **nothing** to do whether your interactive session (module `__main__`) gets the module injected into its namespace, of course.  To ensure module `'goo'` **does** get into the namespace of module `'X'` (for **any** `X`, so of course *including* `__main__`... among many, many others), module `'X'` just needs to `import goo` itself (a very fast operation indeed, if `sys.modules['goo']` is already defined!-).

Comment: So what -v shows is adding the module into sys.modules and to make it available in the current module namespace it needs to be imported in the module scope. That answers my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Python loads the [`site`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) module implicitly when starting up, which may in turn import other modules for its own use. You can pass `-S` to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

They are getting imported (look at sys.modules) and references to the module are created in whichever modules have imported it.

When you do an import in your shell, if the module has already been imported, you will just get a copy of the reference to it in sys.modules